# Get Elements from IE Table via VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

I'm having some problems getting the elements I need from a web page table. The example code from the table is:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="11" class="anscalls">Answered Calls</td>
</tr>
<tr class="daterow">
    <td>01/01/2001</td>
    <td colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td>User 1</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="daterow">
    <td>02/01/2001</td>
    <td colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="changeditem">
    <td>User 1</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="changeditem">
    <td>User 2</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="daterow">
    <td>03/01/2001</td>
    <td colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td>User 1</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="daterow">
    <td>04/01/2001</td>
    <td colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="changeditem">
    <td>User 1</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="changeditem">
    <td>User 2</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="changeditem">
    <td>User 3</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
<tr class="daterow">
    <td>05/01/2001</td>
    <td colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td>User 1</td>
    <td>#</td>
</tr>
```

I'm able to get the information between the "changeditem" class, which is what I need, but I also need the information from the "daterow" class to go along with the "changeditem" information. I'm currently using the following code:

```
For j = 0 To (.Document.getElementsByClassName("changeditem").Length - 1)
    MsgBox .Document.getElementsByClassName("changeditem").Item((j + 0)).InnerText & Chr(44) & _
           .Document.getElementsByClassName("changeditem").Item((j + 1)).InnerText
    j = j + 1
Next
```

Which Outputs:

```
User1,#
User2,#
User1,#
User2,#
User3,#
```

I would need to loop through the entire table, which is much bigger than shown, and get the "daterow" class relevant to the "changeditem" classes, which I cannot figure out how to do.

What I'm aiming to get is:

```
02/01/2001,User 1,#
02/01/2001,User 2,#
04/01/2001,User 1,#
04/01/2001,User 2,#
04/01/2001,User 3,#
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a VBScript answer, but [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) exists specifically for this kind of DOM manipulation and is very widely used, so I'll suggest it anyway. Using jQuery you could do something like the following. I am by no means fluent in jQuery and this will not output the exact desired output, but it illustrates the idea. You could 
do all of this with standard DOM methods, jQuery just makes it much easier.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // get a reference to all changeditem rows
    var $changedItem = $('tr.changeditem');
    // loop the results
    $changedItem.each(function() {
    // contents of first td in tr
    console.log( $(this).children('td').first().text());
    // if there is a sibling tr daterow, get a reference
    var $dateRow = $(this).next('tr.daterow');
    // contents of first td in tr
    console.log( $dateRow.children('td').first().text());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Arno - Thanks for the input. I'm not too good with jQuery but I get the general idea of what's going on. I'll give it a shot in VBScript and let you know. Many thanks!